# Laravel Eloquent many to many with increment which is dependent

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a customer model and a location model with a many to many relationship (Postgres).
Now I also need an incremental number, which is an id for a customer within a location.

Example `customers_locations` table:
[image]
and so on.

So `customer_location_internal_number` should tell the id of a customer within a location. When I add a customer to a location it should increment that number by 1.

Is there a way to do this within a table or do I need another lookup table for that?

The migration looks like that:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('customers_locations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->bigInteger('customer_id');
        $table->bigInteger('location_id');
        $table->bigInteger('customer_location_internal_number');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('customer_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('customers')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('location_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('locations')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Comment: What are you using this `customer_location_internal_number` for? Since `id` is present and auto-incrementing, does this extra auto-incrementing (or manually-incrementing) column actually serve a purpose? You can infer similar information from the following `id`s for `location_id: 1`: `1, 3, 4, 6` vs what the column would contain, which is `1, 2, 3, 4` (notice that each is greater than the last, just with gaps in `id` vs no gaps for `customer_location_internal_number`)

Comment: yeah it does serve a purpose. We need it as an internal identifier for a multi tenant app.

Answer (score 4):

you can use [newPivotQuery](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.html#method_newPivotQuery) to do that, this method Create a new query builder for the pivot table.

for example:

```
$location=getLocation();
$customer=getCustomer();

$location->users()->sync([$user->id]);
$location->users()->newPivotQuery()->where('customer_id',$customer->id)
->where('location_id',$location->id)->increment('customer_location_internal_number');
```